# On/Off Click jQuery

Tags: jquery

I use off() to disable click div but I can't turn it on with on()

Here is my jQuery code :

```js
$("div").off("click");
do something.......
$("div").on("click");
```

Please tell me why ? Thanks you.

Comment: You need to add the event handler callback, `$("div").on("click",function(){ });`

Comment: why do you want to do that... what is the `do something.......` part

Comment: I want disable click because went button clicked many process will run and I don't want people multi click on button.

Answer (score 1):

As for the [official jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the `.on()` function requires both the `event` (i.e. "click") and the `handler` (i.e. doSomething).

```
$("div").on("click", functionToCallWhenClicked);
```

**Edit 1:**

As for your comment, here are some other ways you can attach a click event:

- Via [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

  $("div").bind("click",functionToCallWhenClicked);
- Via [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

  $("div").click(functionToCallWhenClicked);
- Via [native JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

  var y = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      y[i].addEventListener("click", functionToCallWhenClicked);
  }

Comment: You have other way to turn on click went it off ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but see **Edit 1**

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to your handler to pass it to `off` to disable it and another to `one` to enable it.

You have an example on how to `add and remove event handlers on the colored button` in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .on( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#theone", flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Does nothing..." );
});
```